# Automatic case class mapping

Tags: scala, macros

I'm building a web-application using Play and Slick, and find myself in a situation where the user-facing forms are similar, but not exactly the same as the database model.

Hence I have two very similar case classes, and need to map from one to another (e.g. while filling the form for rendering an "update" view).

In the case I'm interested in, the database model case class is a super-set of the form case-class, i.e. the only difference between both is that the database model has two more fields (two identifiers, basically).

What I'm now wondering about is whether there'd be a way to build a small library (e.g. macro-driven) to automatically populate the form case class from the database case class based on the member names. I've seen that it may be possible to access this kind of information via reflection using Paranamer, but I'd rather not venture into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `Dynamic` because I wanted to try it out.  A macro would decide statically whether to emit an apply of a source value method, the default value method, or just to supply a literal.  The syntax could look something like `newFrom[C](k)`.  (Update: see below for the macro.)

```
import scala.language.dynamics
trait Invocable extends Dynamic {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def applyDynamic(method: String)(source: Any) = {
    require(method endsWith "From")
    def caseMethod(s: Symbol) = s.asTerm.isCaseAccessor && s.asTerm.isMethod
    val sm = currentMirror reflect source
    val ms = sm.symbol.asClass.typeSignature.members filter caseMethod map (_.asMethod)
    val values = ms map (m => (m.name, (sm reflectMethod m)()))
    val im = currentMirror reflect this
    invokeWith(im, method dropRight 4, values.toMap)
  }

  def invokeWith(im: InstanceMirror, name: String, values: Map[Name, Any]): Any = {
    val at = TermName(name)
    val ts = im.symbol.typeSignature
    val method = (ts member at).asMethod

    // supplied value or defarg or default val for type of p
    def valueFor(p: Symbol, i: Int): Any = {
      if (values contains p.name) values(p.name)
      else ts member TermName(s"$name$$default$$${i+1}") match {
        case NoSymbol =>
          if (p.typeSignature.typeSymbol.asClass.isPrimitive) {
            if (p.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Int]) 0
            else if (p.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Double]) 0.0
            else ???
          } else null
        case defarg   => (im reflectMethod defarg.asMethod)()
      }
    }
    val args = (for (ps <- method.paramss; p <- ps) yield p).zipWithIndex map (p => valueFor(p._1,p._2))
    (im reflectMethod method)(args: _*)
  }
}
case class C(a: String, b: Int, c: Double = 2.0, d: Double)
case class K(b: Int, e: String, a: String)
object C extends Invocable
object Test extends App {
  val res = C applyFrom K(8, "oh", "kay")
  Console println res      // C(kay,8,2.0,0.0)
}
```

Update: Here is the macro version, more for fun than for profit:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def newFrom[A, B](source: A): B = macro newFrom_[A, B]

def newFrom_[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(source: c.Expr[A]): c.Expr[B] = { 
  import c.{ literal, literalNull } 
  import c.universe._
  import treeBuild._
  import nme.{ CONSTRUCTOR => Ctor } 

  def caseMethod(s: Symbol) = s.asTerm.isCaseAccessor && s.asTerm.isMethod
  def defaulter(name: Name, i: Int): String = s"${name.encoded}$$default$$${i+1}"
  val noargs = List[c.Tree]()

  // side effects: first evaluate the arg
  val side = ListBuffer[c.Tree]()
  val src = TermName(c freshName "src$")
  side += ValDef(Modifiers(), src, TypeTree(source.tree.tpe), source.tree)

  // take the arg as instance of a case class and use the case members
  val a = implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[A]].tpe
  val srcs = (a.members filter caseMethod map (m => (m.name, m.asMethod))).toMap

  // construct the target, using src fields, defaults (from the companion), or zero
  val b = implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[B]].tpe
  val bm = b.typeSymbol.asClass.companionSymbol.asModule
  val bc = bm.moduleClass.asClass.typeSignature
  val ps = (b declaration Ctor).asMethod.paramss.flatten.zipWithIndex
  val args: List[c.Tree] = ps map { case (p, i) =>
    if (srcs contains p.name)
      Select(Ident(src), p.name)
    else bc member TermName(defaulter(Ctor, i)) match { 
      case NoSymbol =>
        if (p.typeSignature.typeSymbol.asClass.isPrimitive) { 
          if (p.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Int]) literal(0).tree
          else if (p.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Double]) literal(0.0).tree
          else ???
        } else literalNull.tree
      case defarg   => Select(mkAttributedRef(bm), defarg.name)
    } 
  } 
  c.Expr(Block(side.toList, Apply(Select(New(mkAttributedIdent(b.typeSymbol)), Ctor), args)))
}
```

With usage:

```
case class C(a: String, b: Int, c: Double = 2.0, d: Double)
case class K(b: Int, e: String, a: String) { def i() = b }
val res = newFrom[K, C](K(8, "oh", "kay"))
```